# Duplicate charts/graphics with different data in the same html page

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, charts, html5-canvas

This is the HTML that display the chart on webpage:

```
<div class="chart" id="p1">
<canvas id="c1" width="560" height="260" style="width: 560px; height: 260px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

and this is the  that generate the chart:

```
<script>
    var c1 = document.getElementById('c1');
    var parent = document.getElementById('p1');
    c1.width = parent.offsetWidth - 40;
    c1.height = parent.offsetHeight - 40;
    var data1 = {
        labels: [
            'Seg',
            'Ter',
            'Qua',
            'Qui',
            'Sex',
            'Sab',
            'Dom'
        ],
        datasets: [{
                fillColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,.1)',
                strokeColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
                pointColor: '#123',
                pointStrokeColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
                data: [
                    190,
                    200,
                    235,
                    390,
                    290,
                    250,
                    250
                ]
            }]
    };
    var options1 = {
        scaleFontColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
        scaleLineColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,1)',
        scaleGridLineColor: 'transparent',
        bezierCurve: false,
        scaleOverride: true,
        scaleSteps: 10,
        scaleStepWidth: 100,
        scaleStartValue: 0
    };
    new Chart(c1.getContext('2d')).Line(data1, options1);
        //@ sourceURL=pen.js
</script>
```

i want to make other charts with different values in the same website page... i already tried duplicate the codes and change id="c1" e id="p1" but nothing...

Comment: Please use the code blocks for any code you put in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a quick fiddle and assumed you were using chart.js

I added a variable data2:

```
var data2 = {
        labels: [
            'A',
            'B',
            'C',
            'D'
            ...
```

and the following html to hold the 2nd chart:

```
<div class="chart" id="p1">
  <canvas id="c2" width="560" height="260" style="width: 560px; height: 260px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Here is a example of it all together.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f4o2y6jg/5/)

Comment: Mr. Ryan Gill, thank u so mutch! solved my problem...you are awesome ;)

Comment: i was trying duplicate all the <script></script>, doesn't worked... but now it works :) tks!